# Performance issues when using Hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, performance, hibernate

I have a query that needs to be run approximately 200 times in a row with different parameters. The query (same as Hibernate produces) itself is extremely fast (sub 1ms) but there is an Hibernate overhead of 2-3 ms for each query that amounts to around 500 ms...

I get the same results using Criteria or Named queries even if I simplify the query and remove all parameters. When using a simple Session.get(Class, Id) it takes less than 1ms to fetch the same entity, so I know that Hibernate is able to fetch and create the object from the database fast enough.

With only one row in the database this takes 3 ms:

```
Criteria criteria = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(TestEntity.class)
criteria.list();
```

While this takes 0 ms:

```
sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().get(TestEntity.class, 1);
```

What is the reason for this overhead and is there any way around it?

Running on: Hibernate 4.3.4.Final, Spring 4.0.2.RELEASE and MySQL 5.5.35.

EDIT:
This is the entity I'm testing on:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TEST")
public class TestEntity implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name = "ID", updatable = false, insertable = false)
public long id;

@Column(name = "VALUE")
public BigDecimal value;

public TestEntity() {
    super();
}

}
```

Comment: Could you post more data? are you using mapped/annotated joins? Is your id a composite-id?

Comment: Getting entity by id use first level cache. So, if entity already in cache it is extreamly fast.

Comment: But even the first get by id is fast. I have also tried to enable/disable L2 cache to see how that affects performance, but it was insignificant changes.